# NSView how cover button?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

NSView button underneath the mouse can still click the button.
How to solve this problem ?
Let NSView cover button, so let the button can not be clicked .

Comment: If you just want a button to not allow click, just set [button setEnabled:FALSE];  Why use NSView?

Comment: I did not get your question. Can you please explain little bit more??

Comment: I would like to create a Tab Switching.

Answer (score 0):

By default NSView doesn't handle mouseDown/mouseUp events, sending it to next objects.
You should handle mouseDown/mouseUp messages on NSView object to not pass events deeper to the responder chain.

Comment: acceptsFirstResponder makes sense only for key events/actions, isn't it?